# Is it okay to use materialized view as data source in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Is it better to create materialized view and its source will still be materialized view? I'm wondering if there will be a performance issue if I do this?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS vw_table
AS
select column2, column2 from vw_table_first
WITH DATA;
```

Comment: That looks odd, but without more information about what you are doing and what you consider as good, we cannot answer the question.

Comment: What problem are trying to solve? For such a simple query on vw_table_first it would be a pretty bad idea, you now have to refresh two views instead of one and it takes more space. Without details this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: A materialized view is essentially a table with contents that are refreshed from a stored query. Since PostgreSQL doesn't support incremental refresh (at least not yet), refreshing a materialized view is equivalent to truncating a table and repopulating it from a query. I wouldn't expect this to cause performance issues; however, testing is better than theorizing.

What is the use case? I suppose it might make sense if the first view's query is expensive to evaluate and the second view's query performs some type of aggregation on the first that is also expensive to evaluate.

Comment: @JohnH Basically, the first materialized view is just a copy of a table and it was created for dashboard view but since we have some problems with performance cuz of many business logic I decided to aggregate separate views. I think I wanna know if there is any standard for this. Is it more okay to directly call the table instead of the first materialized view which is just the same..

Comment: We fix performance issues by improving the SQL where the issue pops up, changing the datamodel, changing indexes, adding new indexes, or whatever. Almost never a materialized view, only for static data.

Comment: Expanding on @FrankHeikens, comments: before resorting to materialized views, explore improvements to the SQL, indexing, and query SQL. The statement that the first materialized view was created for a dashboard suggests differences in the indexing between the table and view. It also leads me to recommend basing the additional aggregating materialized views on the base table. Basing those views on the first materialized view introduces additional, and unnecessary, dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PostgreSQL **materialized view** in a high transaction communication system.

There is a table of sensors with a static number of rows(a few hundred). In the other table, there is a history of actions of these sensors linked via foreign keys (millions of records).

#### Sensors

| Column Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| primary_key | integer | Primary key of the sensor |
| name | varchar(255) | Name of the sensor |

#### Sensor Activity

| Column Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sensor_id | integer | Foreign key to the Sensors table |
| timestamp | timestamp | The date and time the sensor recorded an event |
| value | decimal(10,2) | The value the sensor recorded at that timestamp |

#### Materialized View

| Column Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| primary_key | integer | Primary key of the sensor |
| name | varchar(255) | Name of the sensor |
| last_timestamp | timestamp | The last date and time the sensor recorded an event |
| last_value | decimal(10,2) | The last value the sensor recorded |

1. The materialized view defines the query of sensors with their last activity records(join, subquery, etc.) over the whole table of sensors.
2. The other parts of the system are periodically using this materialized view and filtering results with a simple "where" clause to gather the current status of sensors. It's something like *a real-time view*.

> Main point is, there is only one table scan over the joined table with millions of rows. Materialized view result is reduced only to the number of sensors. Other parts of the system, which are periodically requesting this data need to table scan the materialized view only.

This allowed us to operate **10s database instances** of this system on a simple Azure Linux VM for **50e/month** with each sensor requesting to the server **each second 24/7**.

> When using materialized views in a high transaction system, it's important to keep in mind that refreshing the view can cause contention and lock issues. To mitigate this, you can use a concurrent refresh approach by using the `CONCURRENTLY` keyword when refreshing the view.

Additionally, you may want to **consider indexing** the materialized view to optimize query performance. You can do this by creating an index on the materialized view columns that you frequently query.

I am also recreating the materialized view on each of its schema updates (f.e. adding a new column) the same way as in the query in the answer.

Comment: Keeping track of the most recent reading for each of a few hundred sensors might be more efectively addressed by employing a trigger on the sensor activity table to update the latest read table. This approach mimics the behavior of incrementally refreshed materialixed views such as found in Oracle's RDBMS.

Comment: Good point. In my case materialized view included some other aggregations, the setup, in the end, was more effective than the trigger alternative we have tried previously. This varies according to the scheme complexity and system composition. However, your suggestion is valid and worth consideration.